# MassTransit Worker registration AFTER creating the bus

Tags: masstransit

So I've just pulled the latest MT from NuGet and have been coding with it like a bandit. Love it so far. Now the scenario I am currently implementing is a generic "bus" wrapper that one of the implementations is MT. So in the concrete implementation of the MT I implement the Bus in the constructor... lets call it 'register'

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Registers this instance with a particular bus. Every instance with the same name
    /// will end up on the same bus
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="networkName">The common key to share with other instances on the network</param>
    public void Register(string networkName)
    {
        _bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(x =>
        {
            x.ReceiveFrom("msmq://localhost/the_wheels_on_the_bus");
            x.SetPurgeOnStartup(true);
            x.SetNetwork(networkName);
            x.UseMsmq();
            x.UseMulticastSubscriptionClient();
        });
    }
```

Now, abstract members allow the external code to register handlers using this implementation

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Abstract method to implement on the bus for allow for Responding to Request/Response calls
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TIn">The message to be received from the requester.<remarks>Implements <see cref="ICorrelatedMessage"/>ICorrelatedMessage</remarks> and must have a value</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TOut">The message to be returned to the requester.<remarks>Implements <see cref="ICorrelatedMessage"/>ICorrelatedMessage</remarks> and must have a value</typeparam>
    /// <param name="hostedClassesFunc">The func to invoke to get the appropriate data</param>
    protected override void RegisterHandler<TIn, TOut>(Func<TIn, TOut> hostedClassesFunc)
    {
        _bus.SubscribeHandler<TIn>(msg =>
            {
                var output = hostedClassesFunc.Invoke(msg);
                var context = _bus.MessageContext<TIn>();
                context.Respond(output);
            });

        if (typeof(TIn).GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ICachableItem))
        {
            //mark it as a worker
            //_bus.Worker ?? <-- How can i register this guy here?
        }
    }
```

So the question lies here, Can i even register a worker here? I cant seem to find anywhere to inject a worker on the bus at this point.

Thanks in advance for the help.. i hop the code ends up looking right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There currently isnt any way to do this outside of the configuration block. This would have to be exposed somehow in order to do it after the bus is created.

Answer (score 1):

`_bus.SubscribeConsumer<SubscriberType>()` or `_bus.SubscribeConsumer(instanceOfSubscriberType)` will subscribe normal consumers. If you want distributed worker consumers, you must do it inside the configuration block - we have not exposed the option to do so on the bus itself.

However, it's really important that you subscribe consumers inside the `ServiceBusFactory.New` block. Otherwise MT will start consuming messages on the queue and if there are no consumers registered for that type because you haven't done it yet, messages will end up in the error queue.

I don't see any other code, so this might not be a problem but remember [each IServiceBus needs unique a RecieveFrom](http://www.travisthetechie.com/2013/07/receivefrom-unique-masstransit-problems.html).

Comment: No, I dont have a problem subscribing to the bus, (as you can see from the SubscribeHandler call, but I need to subscribe as a Worker (selective distribution basically)

Comment: Oh, you want a distributed worker? You have to do that in the bus configuration. It's a lot more complicated that just registering a subscriber. I guess it's something that could be exposed - but again, you really need to register all consumers in the configuration block.

Comment: Yes, I understand thats where all the samples have it. I dont see why it needs to happen in the configuration block, If I can subscribe any time I want, why wouldn't I be able to tell the bus that they should be a distributed worker at the same time.

Comment: "I guess it's something that could be exposed" was trying to indicate we haven't exposed that option yet. I guess I just wasn't explicit enough about it.

Comment: Ah... that makes more sense now. Ok thats fine. I was reluctant to dive in the code and expose it myself, but if thats the only option, I could do that. do you know if this is something that would be considered in the future? Also, if you go ahead and respond with that outside of the comments i will mark it as the answer. Thanks for the insight

Comment: Per the mailing list, you're welcomed to make a pull with that. We'll likely accept it. I doubt myself or Chris will jump on doing this on our own. At least open an issue though: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues